# Difficulty with \write

Tags: write

I have a macro `\Content` wich contains several occurence of a macro `\comm`. The latter increases a counter a displays the value of the counter. Calling `\Content` gives the correct output. But i want to write this `\Content` into a file, and i encounter a problem. I guess, this is because `\write` does not like `\stepcounter`. I would like to understand why, and to find a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}     
\begin{document}

\newcounter{myCounter}

\newcommand{\comm}{%
    \stepcounter{myCounter}%
    var\arabic{myCounter} %
}
\def\Content{text \comm text \comm text \comm}

\Content %%%% This works

\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=counter.txt
\immediate\write\tempfile{\Content}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\end{document}
```

PS :  by the way, the error message is `Missing \endcsname inserted.` which i don'T really understand...

**EDIT1** I formulate more precisely my question : the macro `\Content` is given, and i dont' want to modify it. I just know that it contains many occurences of `\comm`. And i want to write the content of `\COntent` into a file, but replacing each `\comm` by something like `var1`, `var2` which increases with some counter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\write` is an expansion context like `\edef` so only expansion happens, no assignments, so no `\def` or counter assignments. You need to increment the counter *before* the write.

If (as noted in the comments) you really want to use expansion then you can't use `\advance` (or equivalently) `\stepcounter` but you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}     
\begin{document}

\newcounter{myCounter}

\def\Content{text \comm text \comm text \comm}

\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=counter.txt
{%
\def\comm#1\expandcomm#2{var#2 #1\expandcomm}
\def\expandcomm#1\relax{}
\immediate\write\tempfile{\Content\expandcomm123456789\relax}%
}%
\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\end{document}
```

which writes:

```
text var1 text var2 text var3
```

Comment: yes, ok, i understand this. But i can't see any way of expanding first completely `\Content` ( and therefore let the counter increase), and then write the result of this expansion into a file... On the other hand, i was always convinced of "with LaTeX, nothing is impossible" ...

Comment: You can't make the counter increase by _expanding_ `\Content` You have to evaluate the assignments which happens "in the stomach" in the terminology of the TeXBook. So you have to do the assignments _first_ save the tokens of each of the three values, and then build the content from that. In other words, do what @egreg says.

Comment: I can't do what @egreg says, because `\Content` is given to me in a tex file. I can only implement something in a documentclass and compile the tex-file with this class, but not modify `\Content` per hand. :(

Comment: well why do you need to increment \comm as the file is written?  (which you can't do) rather than after you read it back?

Comment: I'm not sure whether i understood your question, but the output file is not intended to be read by TeX anymore. It is something like an XML file, if you want. Stupid question : is there an option of pdfLatex, which allows to produce a pure text file, instead of a pdf ?

Comment: Ah  OK. Well in that case you just need to work a bit harder (I'll update answer in a bit)

Comment: David ... that's just great!

Answer (score 5):

Here's how one can do it in Plain TeX. It shouldn't be difficult to turn it into LaTeX.

```
\newcount\roycount

\def\writecontent{\buildcontent\immediate\write\tempfile{\commcontent}}
\def\buildcontent{\def\commcontent{\gobble}\step{text}{var}\step{text}{var}\step{text}{var}}
\def\step#1#2{\advance\roycount 1
  \edef\commcontent{\commcontent\space#1\space#2\number\roycount}}
\def\gobble#1{}

\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.out

\writecontent
\writecontent

\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\bye
```

As you see the string to write is build *before* the write (where assignments can't be performed).

The written file is

```
text var1 text var2 text var3
text var4 text var5 text var6
```

Comment: I don't see how i can easily adapt your solution to my problem, because in my case, `\Content` is defined somewhere else, and i have no control on it. I just know that it contains many occurences of some command `\comm`, which i want to redefine, in order to have this counter effect in the file. I don't know if i am clear... I edited the question.

Comment: @nicolasroy You can't. Your `\Content` command contains instructions to *generate* the numbers, while `\write` needs the already generated numbers: it can't perform computations, only macro expansion.

Comment: @nicolasroy Note that adding any number of `\expandafter` won't cause the assignments to be performed: the primitive `\advance`, which `\stepcounter` ultimately relies on, is *not* expandable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For me, it's hard to accept, that there is no way to perform what i wanted. What is the fundamental reason, why we don't have any version of `def`/`edef` which expands completely and also executes assignements ?

Comment: @nicolasroy Why? Because that's the way it is: macro expansion and assignments are performed at two distinct levels in TeX, so you can't have both at the same time.

Comment: @nicolasroy By most standards the macro expansion layer of TeX can already do rather more than most macro expansion languages. Consider C for example You can't increment values on the cpp macro language, just do textual substitution and very simple test. At some point, you have to stop expanding macros and actually do sometohing. In TeX you can't do any assignments in the macr layer.